# Riemann integral of a function nonzero at countable points is zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, riemann-integration

The problem is as follows.

Let $E = \left\{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ and let $f: [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x) = 1 \text{ for } x \in E$, zero otherwise. Show that $f$ is integrable on [0,1] and find $ \int\limits_0^1 f $

My proof is as follows:

Let $\epsilon >0$. Construct a partition $P =$ {$x_{1},.. , x_{n}$} such that each interval $x_{i} -x_{i-1} < \epsilon$.

Now consider $U(P,f)$ Note that for each $\epsilon >0$, only finitely many points of E lie in $[x_{2},1]$. Let the number of points be M. Then $U(P,f) \leq \epsilon + m\epsilon$ and since $L(P,f) = 0$ for all partitions we have that for $P$, $U(P,f) - L(P,f) \leq (M+1)\epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon >0$ was arbitrary, $f$ is integrable. then it also follows that $\inf U(P,f)=\sup L(P,f)=0 \text{ and thus }  \int\limits_0^1 f = 0$

The solution that I found for this problem involved quite carefully creating the partitions, but I was wondering if this was sufficient, or if theres any important things that I've missed out.

Comment: I believe your solution has no major errors. To be honest, there's a easier way to look at this question, we have $$f\left( x \right) =\chi _E\left( x \right)$$ and this is obvious lebesgue integratable on $\left[ 0,1 \right] $. Since $f$ is lebesgue integratable on $\left[ 0,1 \right] $, it's also reimann integratable. Lastly, $E$ is a null set, we have $\int{f}=0$.

Comment: @oO_ƲRF_Oo  Check this: "Since $f$ is lebesgue integratable on $[0,1]$, it's also reimann integratable".

Comment: @GEdgar Oh, I see that. It was an error. However, if I were to remove that line, it's still technically "integratable", it's still valid, right?

Comment: Burger's proof is the right idea.  But oO's proof does not work.  Function $\chi_E$, with $E$ countable, may or may not be Riemann integrable.

Comment: @oO_ƲRF_Oo - No, it still isn't valid because the question is about Riemann integration (implicitly by the argument Burger crazy made, and also by the selection of the Riemann integration tag).

Comment: @Burger crazy - I don't see anywhere that you are guilty of "quite carefully creating the partitions". Instead you describe an arbitrary partition of lengths $< \epsilon$ (a condition built into the definition of the integral). Where your proof breaks down is that $M$ is dependent on $\epsilon$ (as $\epsilon$ gets smaller $[0,x_1]$ must go smaller, and $M$ will increase). So you have not shown that $(M+1)\epsilon \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. Your overall approach is fine, but you need a tighter argument for this step.